# vlcj mlr special character

Tags: java, encoding, vlcj

I have been stalking this great site for ages. Today I finally decided to create an account when I got stuck on a problem.

My problem is rather basic vlcj executing. I have a program running as an audio player. It is all done except for one problem I cannot seem to figure out.

When someone tried to play a song with a 'é' (e with acute) in the filepath, it seems to translate wrong into the system of vlcj.

Example:
I run:

```
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file:///C:\\test.mp3");
  //(where mediaPlayerComponentis my is my local instantiated 
  // EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent)
```

And this plays fine. But if I run:

```
mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia("file:///C:\\é.mp3");
```

It does not run anything.

- If I call startMedia instead of playMedia, the boolean return value is false.
- I also tried it without the 'file:///' in front of it, this doesnt functionally change a thing, except if I kill the program, then I get a 'libdvdread' error messages such as:

  ```
  libdvdread: Could not open C:\?.mp3 with libdvdcss.
  ```

So to make the question short and sweet: How do I supply the correct 'mrl' to make vlcj play my 'é.mp3'. And/or which MediaOptions are needed to parse the correct encoding (I am assuming my error is here?)

Preemptively sorry for not supplying an SSCCE, I do not think it will be relevant.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you simply run the `file:///C:\\é.mp3` directly from VLC media player instead of your VLCJ application, does it work? If it does, then try to perform URI/URL encoding upon the filepath before passing it to VLCJ's playMedia()

Comment: I forgot to mention (derp.), running directly from VLC or from Winamp for that matter properly does execute the file. As does renaming it, and then running it. So I do think it has to do with the string encoding.

I will give it a try when I got time to get back to this project later tonight. Thank you.

Comment: I tried various setups with encoding it with latin1, UTF-8, UTF-16, Windows-1252 and us-ascii. I have not had success so far. I did notice that when using the us-ascii encoding, the value changes into a similar value which is returned from the 'libdvdread' error parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some interlude I finally found out what went wrong. Apperantly, under windows international characters arent really parsed very well into VLCJ. By adding:

```
<jvmarg value="-Dvlcj.log=DEBUG>
```

to my ANT-run script, I suddenly could play files with an e-acute. Apperantly the decoder of the JVM is finalized when initializing.

Hope this helps someone :-)

Comment: I'm on this exact same issue, thanks for sharing! However adding this arg in my run configs doesn't work for me, still won't play the video or generate a thumbnail if there's an e-acute in the filepath. If I add a "%" (yerr I know it should not be, but it's allowed so it will happen), it's event worst, the JVM crashes completely due to VLC getting a fatal error lol. Did you find a way to get this to work ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Adding the argument worked for me (although I had to rewrite another part of the program which used static strings? wierd.).
After I added the argument, I could truncate my 'play' script back down to:
  
    EmbeddedMediaPlayerComponent mediaPlayerComponent; /* already initialised at this point in runtime */
    mediaPlayerComponent.getMediaPlayer().playMedia((String)trackFile);
  
I am only trying to play mp3's with this script, though. So I do not know about previews or anything of the sorts. Hope this helps!

Comment: Supplemental:
Also, a percent sign needs to be escaped in utf-8, if I recall correctly :-)
A quick google led me to this wiki page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding
   I think the '%' sign might try to resolve to one of the characters defined under the paragraph: 'Percent-encoding reserved characters'. But I am not certain. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution here:

https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/issues/415

This work for me on mac and on windows (vlcj-3.7.0) :

```
  public void play(String mrlPathFile) {
    // URI encode for avoid non ascii character problem in windows!!!
    mrlPathFile = new File(mrlPathFile).toURI().toASCIIString().replace("file:/", "file:///");
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrlPathFile);
}
```

I this could help anyone :)

Answer (score 0):

This is transparently handled in vlcj 2.4.0 onwards by detecting local filenames that contain Unicode characters and converting those filenames to percent-encoded file URLs.

So with current versions of vlcj you should be able to simply pass your filename containing international characters directly to mediaPlayer.playMedia(...).